# System Reserved partition is showing up in “My Computer” along with other partitions

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, windows-8.1, grub, boot-manager

I use Windows 8.1 along with Ubuntu 14.04(Gnome) a dual boot. I used boot manager in Ubuntu to fix the grub in Linux to make Windows boot appear in the grub.

Later I found Windows has two entries in the boot menu as:

- Windows 8 (loader) on dev/sda1
- Windows 8 (loader) on dev/sda2

More to that I see the “System Reserved Partition” appearing in my Windows My Computer.
How do I remove the entry in boot and the “System Reserved Partition” entry?

Help me with the commands as I a beginner to Linux environment.

Comment: http://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/hdg-explains-what-is-the-system-reserved-partition/

Comment: The new partition appeared only after I used bootmanager application in my Ubuntu OS to set back my grub. Is my System Reserved partition appearing in my Boot entry?
If So How can i disable it from appearing (Both ,Partition in Boot and the one appearing in "My Computer")?

Answer (score 0):

Writing here rather than commenting because not sufficient reputation.
In windows 7, you can hide System reserved in my computer( don't know about the other) by using diskpart, and it's 100% working. Please let me know if you want to try it, I am not sure whether it works on win8.1